# Zend Framework: getting request parameters on assertion

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm actually in need to have an assertion which is able to evaluate a parameter coming from the get.

Here's some snippet of code

```
class Something_Acl_RestrictedAssertion implements Zend_Acl_Assert_Interface 
{
    public function assert(Zend_Acl $acl,
                       Zend_Acl_Role_Interface $role = null,
                       Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface $resource = null,
                       $privilege = null)
    {
        //Gets the model and db queries
        $Service = Application_Model_ServiceFactory::getInstance();

        $member = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getRoles();

        foreach ($member as $entity)
        {
        //Ruolo del superviewer convenzioni
        if ($entity->id = 1)
        {
            if (something->getRequest()->getParam('hello'))
                    {
                         //Black magick
                    }
        }
...}
}
```

I'm looking for a way right now to get to the parameters of the page the assertion is checking, avoiding, if possible, to create subclasses or wrappers.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply,

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$action = $request->getParam('action');
//$request is a Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract instance
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, it seems that my problem also related by the fact I was in a situation where I had first to deal how to get the right "resource" of the controller. After that, this worked

Answer (score 0):

Either general way, it is not disallowed in ZF:

```
isset($_GET['hello']);
```

Or by

```
$get = $this->getRequest()->getQuery();
isset($get->hello);
// or if this throws a warning:
property_exists($get, 'hello');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.request.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.5/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.dataacess